# From whence %E2%80%8E at the end of post link

Tags: urls

I have a custom post type called "employees" (I'm using Custom Post Type UI plugin). I've created few posts of "employees" type. For getting link to post I'm using this code:

```
$original_permalink = get_permalink($original_post_id);
...
<a href="<?=$original_permalink?>‎"><?=RU_LINK?></a>
```

When I follow this link I get 404 error and URL like this: http://site.local/employees/lana/**%E2%80%8E**

I read that the reason is copy/paste of post title from MS Word or something like this, but I wrote titles manually. So this is not the reason. When I do code like this

```
echo $original_permalink = get_permalink($original_post_id);
```

I get correct URL. And when I see page code (Ctrl+U) it's correct too.

By the way, when I've created posts of default type ("post") such problems were not observed. 
What the reason for such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Mystic! I don't know why, but if I use code like this:

```
<?php
    $original_permalink = get_the_permalink($original_post_id);
?>

<a href="<?=$original_permalink?>‎"><?=RU_LINK?></a>
```

I get %E2%80%8E at the end of URL.

But if i use different names of variables my code works fine:

```
<?php
    $ru_link = get_the_permalink($original_post_id);
?>
<a href="<?=$ru_link?>"><?=RU_LINK?></a>
```